# Laravel Blade @yield and escaping

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, yield

In Laravel 5 I have a master template containing:

```
<title>@yield('title') | Site Name</title>
```

And in my view I have:

```
@extends('master')

@section('title', $client->name)

...
```

The problem is, the @yield does not escape the data passed to it. So far, the only solution I've found is to manually escape the data like so:

```
@section('title', e($client->name))
```

Is this the best method? It means I have to manually escape data on every view that I use a variable. I don't see a way to escape the @yield directive from the master template - using `{{ }}` or `e()` around the @yield doesn't work.

Comment: I didn’t realise `@​yield`-ed values weren’t escaped. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not do the following:

```
@section('title') {{$client->name}} @endsection
```

This is at least then consistent with escaping data in the rest of your views. The way you have it, you may be very likely to miss an `e()`. With the above, you will be able to see immediately when you render the view if you have not escaped.

UPDATE

What about using the raw PHP:

```
<title> <?php echo e($__env->yieldContent('title')); ?> | Site Name</title>
```

This is what the blade template engine replaces the `@yield` with, but I've add the escape helper.

This should mean you don't need to escape `@section`. I think this will work, haven't tried it.

Comment: This would get my vote. Does @DisgruntledGoat have a reason for not doing it this way?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was is that it's actually escaped the string I passed, like this:

```
@section('title', 'String with \' string')
```

In result in actual HTML you'll see `&#039;` instead of actual `'`.

Workaround for this is to write section like this:

```
@section('title'){!! "String with ' string" !!}@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
@section('title')
 {{ $client->name }}
@stop
```

Comment: Is `@stop` still supported in Laravel 5? I was under the impression they removed it.

Comment: I think \@endsection is technically the right way to do this, but I haven't had any trouble with \@stop in my L5 apps.